# Handling events with PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, event-handling

How can you handle events thrown by .NET object using PowerShell v2?  Can someone point me to a simple code sample?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the docs on the [Register-ObjectEvent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx) cmdlet. Be sure to use the -full parameter.  It has some good examples of usage including this one:

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 500
$timer.Start()
$job = Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $timer -eventName Elapsed `
       -sourceIdentifier Timer.Random `
       -Action {$random = Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 100; $random}
Receive-Job $job
```

You might also want to check out this [PowerShell Eventing QuickStart blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/06/11/powershell-eventing-quickstart.aspx).  Note that some of the cmdlet names have changed e.g. Get/Remove-PsEvent is now just Get/Remove-Event.

Comment: I don't understand what the output of this script should be. Nothing displays in the console. How do I read the value of `$random`?

Comment: @isme Use the call operator on the job: `& $job.module {$random}`.

Comment: @isme Talking to yourself, eh?  :-) BTW I just modified the answer to use the Receive-Job cmdlet. But your suggestion would also be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the Receive-Job version. My suggestion no longer works on your code example because there is no `$random` variable to read.

Comment: @isme I updated it so that both approaches should work.  Thanks for the suggestion.